# sql query to calculate monthly growth percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to build a query with 4 columns (sql 2005).

```
Column1: Product
Column2: Units sold
Column3: Growth from previous month (in %)
Column4: Growth from same month last year (in %)
```

In my table the year and months have custom integer values. For example, the most current month is 146 - but also the table has a year (eg 2011) column and month (eg 7) column.

Is it possible to get this done in one query or do i need to start employing temp tables etc??

Appreciate any help.

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KS,
To do this on the fly, you could use subqueries.

```
SELECT product, this_month.units_sold,
    (this_month.sales-last_month.sales)*100/last_month.sales,
    (this_month.sales-last_year.sales)*100/last_year.sales
    FROM (SELECT product, SUM(units_sold) AS units_sold, SUM(sales) AS sales
            FROM product WHERE month = 146 GROUP BY product) AS this_month,
         (SELECT product, SUM(units_sold) AS units_sold, SUM(sales) AS sales
            FROM product WHERE month = 145 GROUP BY product) AS last_month,
         (SELECT product, SUM(units_sold) AS units_sold, SUM(sales) AS sales
            FROM product WHERE month = 134 GROUP BY product) AS this_year
    WHERE this_month.product = last_month.product
      AND this_month.product = last_year.product
```

If there's a case where a product was sold in one month but not another month, you will have to do a left join and check for null values, especially if last_month.sales or last_year.sales is 0.

Comment: This gives 1080.00 as the percent increase when the previous month sales is 404683.00and the current month sales is 436493.00. I'm pretty sure the answer should be 7.86.?

Comment: Could you modify the first line of the select statement to: SELECT product, this_month.units_sold, this_month.sales, last_month.sales, last_year.sales and see if those three sales numbers are correct.  I just ran this against one of my local tables and it's giving the correct percentages, so I'd like to see what values the query is calculating on.  Regards, Brian

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly guessing as the structure of the table provided is the result table, right? You will need to do self-join on month-to-previous-month basis:

```
SELECT <growth computation here> 
  FROM SALES s1 LEFT JOIN SALES s2 ON (s1.month = s2.month-1) -- last month join
                LEFT JOIN SALES s3 ON (s1.month = s3.month - 12) -- lat year join
```

where `<growth computation here>` looks like

```
((s1.sales - s2.sales)/s2.sales * 100), 
((s1.sales - s3.sales)/s3.sales * 100)
```

I use `LEFT JOIN` for months that have no previous months. Change your join conditions based on actual relations in month/year columns.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got them all:

```
SELECT
  Current_Month.product_name, units_sold_current_month,
  units_sold_last_month * 100 / units_sold_current_month prc_last_month,
  units_sold_last_year * 100 / units_sold_current_month prc_last_year
FROM
  (SELECT product_id, product_name, sum(units_sold) units_sold_current_month FROM MyTable WHERE YEAR = 2011 AND MONTH = 7) Current_Month
  JOIN
  (SELECT product_id, product_name, sum(units_sold) units_sold_last_month FROM MyTable WHERE YEAR = 2011 AND MONTH = 6) Last_Month
  ON Current_Month.product_id = Last_Month.product_id
  JOIN 
  (SELECT product_id, product_name, sum(units_sold) units_sold_last_year FROM MyTable   WHERE YEAR = 2010 AND MONTH = 7) Last_Year
  ON Current_Month.product_id = Last_Year.product_id
```

Comment: Hmmm... your formula does not give the increase in percent, which is what I was after. This will give the previous month's value as a percentage of the current month (as far as i can see). I will try the join technique though.